# Calculate inside input like a calculator

Tags: jquery

Without showing a calculator, I am setting up a jQuery function to calculate directly in an input as its typed. I am close, the addition routines working ok-ish. The subtraction is a little quirky as i am trying to enter test data it doesn't quite flow.

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Lusaj8kc/4/

So as i type in 15 + 5 + 7 + , i get my answer of 27. I have the plus key running the requested operation a little out of sequence. Since it automatically shows the results, no enter key should be needed, and I want to hook the enter key into a form submit anyway.

If i type in 15 + 5 - 7 i would need to press - again, and results in 3 as its subtracting 5 from 15 first.
I would need to type in 15 + 5 + 7 - to get 13

How could i get this to behave more calculator-ish? Similar to the built in Windows Calculator. This will be for simple money calculations, so wont be allowing multiply and divide or others for simplicity.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.calcInMyBox = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            decimalPlaces: 2
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            var calcHolder = 0.00;
            var calcDisplay = "";

            $(this).keypress(function (e) {
                //Prevent letters from being entered
                var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9\.]+$");
                var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
                if (!regex.test(key)) { e.preventDefault(); return false; }
            });

            $(this).keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 27) {
                    //Escape Key To Clear
                    calcHolder = 0.00;
                    calcDisplay = "";
                    $(".CalculatorData").html("");
                    $(this).val(calcHolder.toFixed(settings.decimalPlaces)).select();
                }
                if (e.which == 107) {
                    //Add Value
                    calcHolder = Number(this.value) + calcHolder;
                    $(".CalculatorData").html(calcDisplay + this.value + " + ");
                }
                else if (e.which == 109) {
                    //Subtract Value
                    calcHolder = calcHolder - Number(this.value);
                    $(".CalculatorData").html(calcDisplay + this.value + " - ");
                }
                if (e.which == 107 || e.which == 109) {
                    calcDisplay = $(".CalculatorData").html();
                    $(this).val(calcHolder.toFixed(settings.decimalPlaces)).select();
                    console.log(calcHolder);
                }
            });

        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(".jqNewAmount").calcInMyBox({ decimalPlaces: 2});
```

**UPDATE:** https://jsfiddle.net/Lusaj8kc/6/
Was able to implement eval per Davids suggestion. It places the operations outside of the input, and evals on that data, recording the answer into the input. Added tab and enter key calculations.

Comment: Does not work in Chrome at all

Comment: @mplungjan yes it does. I'm on chrome now. is jquery not loading in the jsFiddle for you? F12 and see if console showing errors?

Answer (score 2):

Would it be possible for you to just use `eval`, like this?

```js
var $eq = $('#eq');
var $ans = $('#ans');

$eq.keyup(function(e) {
  try{
    var ans = eval($eq.val()).toFixed(2);
    $ans.val(ans);
  } catch(e) { $ans.val(''); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Equation: <input id="eq" />
<br>
Answer: <input id="ans"/>
```

Comment: ok it seems to calculate cleanly, but would like the answer in the input and the caclulations outside... lemme see if i can switch er up

Comment: Modified to put answer in an input.

Comment: updated using your eval for inline input calculations - https://jsfiddle.net/Lusaj8kc/6/

Answer (score 0):

David784's answer was really right on.  One could consider adding a error message that could be thrown, and execution would continue with a message on the console.Then the users input would still be junk.  Also, Adding a "please enter a number" message could be shown instead of his suggested blank.  But, David784 hit the mark in expecting that the user enter a number, and not explain it. The javascript function .toFixed() did the rest!